# How to explicitly declare and define a Clock and Reset in Bluespec BSV (Bluespec SystemVerilog)

Tags: reset, clock, bluespec

How to explicitly declare and define a Clock and Reset in Bluespec BSV (Bluespec SystemVerilog) language. This is should be simple as a bigger, but the resources are little and user manual is overwhelming